# synapse arm template not concating string comma during synapse deployment

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-synapse-pipeline

I am using arm template artifacts of synapse and then parametrizing it while deploying synapse through pipeline. The issue that spark job definition property has string having comma in and synapse fails to identify comma despite escaping it. I would really appreciate help on how to concatenate both string for synapse deployment.

"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "[concat(parameters('Txp-Processing-_sparkJob_driverExtraJavaOptions'), '/Build/Confs/txp-allocation-mrr-populateexistingallocations-ots.conf -Detwlogger.component=sparkdriver -DlogFilter.filename=SparkLogFilters.xml -DpatternGroup.filename=SparkPatternGroups.xml -Dlog4jspark.root.logger=INFO ,console ,RFA, ETW, Anonymizer -Dlog4jspark.log.dir=/var/log/sparkapp/${user.name} -Dlog4jspark.log.file=sparkdriver.log -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/driver-log4j.properties -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:Tier4CompileThreshold=150000 -noverify')]"

how to concatenate string having comma within arm template which is used by synapse deployment.